# How to overwrite value of observed node?

Tags: r, jags, rjags

New to JAGS and working with a model referred in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13428-012-0300-3). Looks like the authors used a previous version of JAGS that was closer to BUGS since at some point, this appears in the model block (lines 28-29):

```
  z[i,1:(K-1)] ~ dmnorm(etas[i,], omega)
  z[i,K] <- 0
```

JAGS complains with the following error:

```
Error in setParameters(init.values[[i]], i) : Error in node z[1,4]
Cannot overwrite value of observed node
```

Checking the JAGS manual, the error is evident. In section A.4 Data Transformations, it states that BUGS allows to put a stochastic node twice on the left hand side of a relation. As a workaround, it offers to include the data transformation on a separate `data` block. It still fails.

Has anybody tried to replicate this work and found success? Any hints?

---

Full JAGS model below. The suspect assignments are `z[i,K] <- 0` and `beta[j,K] <- 0`

```
data {
   for (j in 1:(K-1)) {
      for (i in 1:N) {
         ones[i,j] <- 1
      }
      for (k in 1:K) {
         C[j,k] <- equals(j,k) - equals(k,K)
      }   
   }
   R <- (K-1) * C %*% t(C)
   lower <- -1e+3
   upper <-  1e+3
}
model { 
   for (i in 1:N) {
      for (k in 1:(K-1)) {
         bounds[i,k,1] <- equals(y[i,k],K)*lower + inprod(z[i,], equals(y[i,],y[i,k] + 1))
         bounds[i,k,2] <- equals(y[i,k],1)*upper + inprod(z[i,], equals(y[i,],y[i,k] - 1))
         ones[i,k] ~ dinterval(z[i,k], bounds[i,k,])
         etas[i,k] <- inprod(x[i,], beta[,k])
      }
      z[i,1:(K-1)] ~ dmnorm(etas[i,], omega)
      z[i,K] <- 0
   }
   for (j in 1:(P+1)) {
      for (k in 1:(K-1)) {
         beta[j,k] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3)
      }
      beta[j,K] <- 0
      for (k in 1:K) {   
          for (t in 1:K) {
             beta.identified[j,k,t] <- (beta[j,k] - beta[j,t])*sqrt(const)
          }
      }
   }
   omega ~ dwish(R, K-1)
   sigma <- inverse(omega)
   const <- pow(K/exp(logdet(sigma)), 1/K)
   sigma.identified <- sigma*const
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to the paper author and acknowledged that a posterior release of JAGS broke the original code. In his words, the solution is...

"But there is a relatively simple work-around that involves using an extra variable that effectively represents the K-1 differences in the latent responses and then mapping that to the Z variable. I'll attach a file that contains the updated scripts from that paper. This does require a change in the way that initial values are created for the algorithm. The `makeinits` function (in the data.R file) has been updated as well."

The new model code is provided below:

```
data {
   for (j in 1:(K-1)) {
      for (i in 1:N) {
         ones[i,j] <- 1
      }
      for (k in 1:K) {
         C[j,k] <- equals(j,k) - equals(k,K)
      }   
   }
   R <- (K-1) * C %*% t(C)
   lower <- -1e+3
   upper <-  1e+3
}
model { 
   for (i in 1:N) {
      for (k in 1:(K-1)) {
         bounds[i,k,1] <- equals(y[i,k],K)*lower + inprod(z[i,], equals(y[i,],y[i,k] + 1))
         bounds[i,k,2] <- equals(y[i,k],1)*upper + inprod(z[i,], equals(y[i,],y[i,k] - 1))
         ones[i,k] ~ dinterval(z[i,k], bounds[i,k,])
         etas[i,k] <- inprod(x[i,], beta[,k])
      }
      u[i,1:(K-1)] ~ dmnorm(etas[i,], omega)
      z[i,1:(K-1)] <- u[i,1:(K-1)]
      z[i,K] <- 0
   }
   for (j in 1:(P+1)) {
      for (k in 1:(K-1)) {
         beta[j,k] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3)
      }
      beta[j,K] <- 0
      for (k in 1:K) {   
          for (t in 1:K) {
             beta.identified[j,k,t] <- (beta[j,k] - beta[j,t])*sqrt(const)
          }
      }
   }
   omega ~ dwish(R, K-1)
   sigma <- inverse(omega)
   const <- pow(K/exp(logdet(sigma)), 1/K)
   sigma.identified <- sigma*const
}
```

with new `makeinits` function:

```
makeinits <- function (y) {
    n <- nrow(y)
    m <- ncol(y)
    z <- matrix(NA, n, m)
    for (i in 1:n) { 
        z[i,] <- sort(rnorm(m))[rank(-y[i,])]
        z[i,] <- z[i,] - z[i,m]
        }
    z[,-ncol(y)]
}
```